# class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class moduleapi.interaction.FlowPicklistValue

Tags: visual-workflow

I am using a Screen Flow to handle a custom Membership form. I have found an issue where if a field marked as "required" is not filled in, and the user hits "Next" on the screen flow it results in an error that reads as follows:

`class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class moduleapi.interaction.FlowPicklistValue (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; moduleapi.interaction.FlowPicklistValue is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @2b5825fa)`

The same issue arises if every field is filled in properly and the user attempts to hit "Next", then "Previous" on the next screen. I am using picklists on the page as well as other fields, but this issue arises when a non-picklist required field is left blank, so I don't understand why it's occurring.

I found a post describing a similar issue [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003ebzQAA), but it describes Dependent Picklists, which I am not using in my solution. I'm new to Salesforce development, so some help on this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you, but I had the same problem recently. Same exact issue when "Next" and "Previous" buttons were pressed.

I was able to resolve it easily with checking the "manually assign variables (advanced)" checkbox (see below screenshot).

[image]

You do not necessarily need to enter anything into the values for the output fields (i.e. you can leave them blank), unless you need them for other reasons.